# Heroku ENOENT: no such file or directory due to faulty express.js routing

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, phaser-framework

I seen other people running into the same issue but I am starting to believe that I have a deeper issue with my express file setup since other solutions are not fixing it.

The idea that I had was to have a main page and then add folders for each of my projects. This is my folder structure:

[image]

And the code in the index.js is simply this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 5000!')
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static('asteroid'));

app.get('/asteroid', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/asteroid/');
});
```

Now like many other question out there, the issue that I see in the log is `"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/asteroid/index.html'"`. The app tries to go to `/app` and it can't find my files on there. I seem to be missing something simple.

Any idea what can be causing this in my case? I tried `{ root: __dirname }`, joining everything with `path()`, and placed `__dirname` everywhere with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file listing shows Asteroid uppercase.  Maybe try renaming it to be lowercase everywhere?
If you're using express static then you don't need routes for each file.  So maybe just use static or just use routes.

Comment: Haha... amazing!. Testing that right now. I have not considered that.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much!